# Oracle rand() function

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I tried to select a random data from table employees with query `rand()` but it can happen

```
SELECT email FROM employees
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

and the output is:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Can somebody tell me why??

Comment: can you provide the schema of the database?

Comment: There is neither a `LIMIT` in Oracle nor a `rand()` function. Please read the manual

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Oracle equivalent of `rand()` is `dbms_random.value`.

The Oracle equivalent of `limit` is either a subquery with `rownum` or (in Oracle 12) `fetch first xx row only`.  So, one of these should work:

```
select email
from employees
order by dbms_random.value
fetch first 1 row only;
```

or:

```
select email
from (select email
      from employees
      order by dbms_random.value
     ) e
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

To speed-up operations on large table, you might use the `SAMPLE` clause to randomly extract a sample of data from your table, and then randomly pick one data from that sample:

```
select email from 
( SELECT email,ROWNUM rn
  FROM employees SAMPLE(5)
  --                    ^
  --      each row has 5% chance of being picked-up
  --      adjust that depending your table size and/or your needs
  ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
where rn = 1;
```

---

An other idea is that you don't need a full sort just to extract *one* random row. For example, you might want to try that alternate approach:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT email, ROWNUM rn
    FROM employees
  ),
  rnd as (
    SELECT TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE))) AS value FROM DUAL
  )

SELECT cte.email FROM cte JOIN rnd
    ON cte.rn = rnd.value;
```

I don't know if Oracle is able to "properly" optimize such queries though.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle doesn't have LIMIT. You can try this:

```
select email from 
(SELECT email, row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value) rw FROM employees)
where rw = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, 1 )) as RND,
....
....
....

From (your_table)

Order by RND
```

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, you should add some commentary which explains why it works.